# how to set PDF document permission in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf-generation, quartz-graphics

I need to create PDF documents with security and restrictions in cocoa application. I found lots of useful code in stack overflow as well as on Google. The only thing which is missing is encrypting PDF with additional encryption methods like (128bit RC4,128Bit AES) and permissions like in following link.

[Set Privileges on PDF Document](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/set-privileges-on-pdf-document.html)

[Encrypt PDF File Using Different Encryption Types](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/encrypt-pdf-file-using-different-encryption-types.html)

Please let me know how to achieve the above using Quartz or PDF Kit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"letMeIn", kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, @"r3adm3", kCGPDFContextUserPassword, nil];
[myPDFDocument writeToFile: @"/some/path" withOptions: options];
```

See the [CGPDFContext documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000957) for more information about the options, including disabling copying and printing.

Comment: thanks. I have already checked all the "Auxiliary Dictionary Keys" and didn't find a way to set permission and encryption method given in my links.

Comment: You can also send the same dictionary to PDFDocument -dataRepresentationWithOptions: